# Machine account or local user account

Tags: active-directory

I am working on an active directory environnement.

I am connected to a workstation as a local administrator.
I have launched a powershell console and I have typed:

```
$Env:UserName
```

I have multiple workstations. Sometimes I can see the local administrator name and sometime I see the AD machine account.

This is strange because I can run powerview and query Active Directory as local administrator. How can this be possible ?

How can I swap (impersonate) between this local administrator account and AD machine user account ?

Thanks

Comment: What does `whoami /all` show?

Comment: whoami displays informations about local administrator

Comment: A local administrative account running an elevated process will use the machine's credentials when accessing network resources.

Comment: You should never see the machine name. Please try the same on a cmd shell with %username%. What @Semicolon says is surely incorrect. There is no automatic impersonation of the system account when accessing network resources - you will always be asked for credentials. If you are not asked, this implies that there are saved credentials for that resource present that are used automatically.

Comment: Indeed.  It is a local administrative account -- acting as system - that would access the network resources using the machine's account.

Comment: There is not enough information here about how OP is "connected" to these workstations. Is it interactive logon? Is it a PSSession? Is it some other remote administration tool like PsExec, dameware, or RDP? How would one reproduce the behavior is what I want to know.